# How can I add activities information in the email sent by civirules?

Tags: email, activities, civirules, activity

I have a rule to trigger based on when an activity is added and send an email. I would like to add the content of the activity i.e. activity type, description in the email sent by civirules. Is it something possible to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the available tokens in the template you are sending. Alternatively you could create your own tokens that can be filled with the data that is available from CiviRules?

Comment: Thanks! I dont see any activities token in default list though.

Comment: There are some extensions with additional tokens, not sure what is in those but you can check? https://civicrm.org/extensions?title=token&body_value=&field_extension_civi_use_target_id=All&status=All&field_extension_ready_value=All. And this one is for activities specifically: https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-tokens.